# JavaScript TypeError in 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to read value from a json into a 2D array

```
  var arr = [[],[]];
  var i = 0;
    var file = './test.json';
    jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, objs) {
        let i = 0;
        objs.forEach(function (obj) {
            arr[i][0] = obj["outcount"];
            arr[i][1] = obj["gateID"];
            arr[i][2] = obj["timestamp"];
            arr[i][3] = obj["eventCode"];
            i = i + 1;
        });
        console.log(arr[2]);
    })
```

For i = 0 and i = 1, it works fine but on i = 2 it gives the error

> TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: `arr` only contains 2 elements, that you get with `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` but when you try to get a 3rd, non-existant element with `arr[2]` you get `undefined` and then you try to access a property of `undefined` which gives you that TypeError

Comment: @MikaelLennholm How do I create a 2D array with no limit on elements?

Comment: See Musa's answer. Arrays don't have a set number of elements nor a maximum number of elements, you can add and remove from an array freely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array `arr` only has two items in it, the empty arrays.
So `arr[0]` is the first one and `arr[1]` is the second one that's all, `arr[2]` doesn't exist. If you had `arr = [[],[],[]];` then `arr[2]` would work but you can see the problem there.
Best option is to create the sub-array before you use it.
Also, the forEach function provides a counter which can be used instead of creating your own.

```
var arr = [];
var file = './test.json';
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, objs) {
    objs.forEach(function (obj, i) {
        arr[i] = [];
        arr[i][0] = obj["outcount"];
        arr[i][1] = obj["gateID"];
        arr[i][2] = obj["timestamp"];
        arr[i][3] = obj["eventCode"];
        i = i + 1;
    });
    console.log(arr[2]);
})
```

Comment: I would also suggest using the index provided by the `forEach()` function instead of creating your own counter

Comment: I see javascript handles arrays differently than most other languages. The square brackets depict separate arrays instead of dimensions.

Comment: @Arpit Yes, arrays in Javascript are just objects with some dedicated syntactic sugar. There are no true arrays in JS.